# unable to bootstrap commerce engine after json config changes

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am trying to initialize the bootstrap for commerce engine after a change made on payment plugin json file. i am calling the bootstrap method in the postman (screen shot attached) with the input parameters but i am getting only 401 response. please let me know whether iam passing some incorrect parameters. also the authorization api is successfull and i can able to add the token in bootstrap method

[image]

Comment: I tried to follow this link "https://tothecore.sk/2018/07/25/setting-up-development-environment-with-postman-and-sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9/" . as per the link after setting global variable as sitecoreidtoken now i am geting the result as internal server error.

Comment: First you should not edit that token manually. There is a postman call GetToken, which sets it automatically. Then, can you please add the error you get now? Maybe the json is incorrect now.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling the antiforgery field value to false in config.json. it is working as expected. i can able to call the bootstrap method with 200 status.